# ElementTree.findall returns none

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I want to find all password attribute while xml parsing and replace that with string "password".  To find the password attribute I tried findall(), but it return "None".

Python version: python2.6

Sample code :

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
a= tree.parse("/home/xxxx/securityfile_test.xml")
z = tree.findall(".//password")
print z
```

Can any one please help

Sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<security xmlns="http:xxxxx">

  <group name="Abc" description="xxxxx.">
    <rMember ref="A"/>
  </group>
  <user name="yyyy" password="**####***">
    <gMember ref="A"/>
  </user>
  <group name="oooo" description="XXXXx">
    <rMember ref="O"/>
  </group>
   <user name="zzzz" password="****###***">
    <gMember ref="A"/>
  </user>
  </security>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will pull out the elements you need, update the attribute values and dump the xml result:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Etree
tree = Etree.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)
z = root.findall(".//*[@password]")
for elm in z:
    elm.attrib['password'] = "Password"
    print(Etree.dump(root))
```

I could only test on 2.7.12 as it's the only version I have for python2.  I would definitely recommend you upgrade if you can, but this should hopefully give you a point in the right direction if you can't.

Comment: If I try this I get a "SyntaxError: invalid descendant" exception.

Comment: File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 88, in __init__
    raise SyntaxError("unsupported path syntax (%s)" % op)
SyntaxError: unsupported path syntax (@)

Comment: Sorry,I didn't realise the XPath syntax was so limited in that version.  I've updated my answer with but Iike @jfowkes I can only test on 2.7 (2.7.12 to be exact.)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: OP is using Python 2.6, this answer only valid for Python 2.7+**

See the [elementtree documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).

To select elements based on attributes, you need to use a different syntax. If you use:

```
z = tree.findall(".//*[@password]")
```

This will work. The `*` means 'select all elements', the [@password] means 'with the password attribute'.

Results on your XML file with Python 2.7.12:

```
[<Element '{http:xxxxx}user' at 0x585ad30>, <Element '{http:xxxxx}user' at 0x585ae48>]
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)

Comment: I believe this is only valid for Python 2.7+.